# Windows でNFCタグに任意の情報を書き込むには？

Tags: c#

先日業務でお客様に提案する為に下記のようなNFCタグとハンディリーダーを購入しました。
https://goo.gl/yoWA3g

そして↑のNFCタグに情報を書き込む為に、Sonyの下記の製品を購入しました。
https://www.sony.co.jp/Products/felica/consumer/products/RC-S380.html

NFCのタグはお客様社内でしか使用しないので、自由な書き込みエリアに仕様を決めてデータを書き込みたいのですが、肝心のWindows用のNFCタグ書き込みソフトが見当たりません。

またWindows10Store等でNFCの書き込みソフトウェアをみつけましたら、Sonyの製品では全く動かないようです。

NFCタグを使ったシステムソリューションは世の中沢山あると思いますが、皆さまはどのようにNFCタグに任意の情報を書き込んでおられますか？Android端末のソフトは沢山あるようなのですが、そのようなモバイルソフトウェアで書き込んでおられるでしょうか？

ご意見ください。

Comment: `C#`のタグが付いていますが、質問としては「アプリ開発」を目的としたものと「既存のアプリを探してる」のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: Sonyさんの製品の話なので、ここで聞くよりSonyさんに問い合わせた方が...というのはダメでしょうか？不適切であればコメント削除します。

Answer (score 1):

SONYの法人のお客様向けページで、[SDK for NFC for Windows](https://www.sony.co.jp/Products/felica/business/products/sdk.html)を参照してください。

詳しい製品情報はこちら [SDK for NFC](https://www.sony.co.jp/Products/felica/business/products/ICS-D004.html)。
動作環境などの情報は[SDK for NFC 　動作環境一覧表](https://www.sony.co.jp/Products/felica/business/products/ICS-D004_environment.html)になります。

---

追記
個人で実験・公開されたものがあったので紹介。
実験レベルであっていまいちなようですが、使い方の参考になるのでは？

[NFCのこと](https://sites.google.com/site/hiro99ma/nfc), [実践!](https://sites.google.com/site/hiro99ma/nfc/experiment), [SDK for NFC Starter Kitを使う](https://sites.google.com/site/hiro99ma/nfc/experiment/sdk-for-nfc-starter-kit) , [APIをまとめたライブラリを作る](https://sites.google.com/site/hiro99ma/nfc/experiment/sdk-for-nfc-starter-kit/wrap)

> やりたかったこと
>   ◾Windowメッセージの処理がよくわからないので、隠してしまいたい。
>   ◾FeliCa LiteとMIFARE Ultralightはよく使うので、簡単に使えるようにしておきたい。

GitHubに公開されているラッパーソース
[hirokuma/NfcStarterKitWrap](https://github.com/hirokuma/NfcStarterKitWrap)

使用予定タグのIC:NXP NTAG213は、NFC Forum Type2タグですが、製造元からMIFARE UltralightとNFC Forum Type2は互換に出来る[MIFARE Ultralight as Type 2 Tag](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1303.pdf)という資料が出ています。

Comment: 有り難うございます！丁度今同じページを確認していました（笑）